# Magento2 Settings

Tags: magento2

When I toggle Client Side Less Compilation and save it on a Magento 2.2.2 site, it throws the following error:

> 500 internal server error

This is the log:

```
[Fri Jul 27 13:13:36.324051 2018] [:error] [pid 20125] [client 5.255.250.135:46655] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation::processContent() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\FallbackContext, instance of Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\Context given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php on line 90 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php:107\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php(90): Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation->processContent('15859f29777d5d9...', '@import 'third-...', '', Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\File\\Context))\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/PreprocessorStrategy.php(74): Magento\\Developer\\Model\\View\\Asset\\PreProcessor\\FrontendCompilation->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\As in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FrontendCompilation.php on line 107
```

I only have access to SSH and SFTP, how can I try to fix this? I appreciate any answer.

Comment: I would look at your web server error logs. Will give you a better understanding of what is going on.